# git push fails in permissions setting up fresh gitosis on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, git

I got permission prob with first test project on gitosis server, ubuntu lucid server

Used this howto https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git

changes, commits and push on gitosis-admin worked.

Then i created the test project and local repo and committed sth., set master as in howto but then on push i got:

```
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Maybe it's necessary to tell that we use NFS and I am not sure about how to handle the keys.

I saw that the key i put in `/srv/gitosis/.ssh/authorized_keys` had mylogin@server at the end. So I generated one on the new box i've been working on since tw weeks now and appended it to the file.

w/o.success - so I tried  `AllowUsers gitosis` in server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restarted ssh server.

Now i am asked for `gitosis@server's password:`  !!

Switched back but keeps asking.

Please give a hint how to check further. - Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gitosis is no longer maintained and supported by the author; most people usually recommend gitolite instead which has much better documentation and more features: http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite